# how to developed media player in python that works base on face detection?

Tags: python-3.x, media-player, face-detection

I want to develop a Windows Media Player in Python that works using face detection.

If a face detected using a webcam then the video will play, otherwise it is paused. So where should I start, what tools are used for media players and face detection in Python?

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to look at OpenCV for face detection using images from the webcam.

Comment: fine, what you have tried so far to achieve what you have imagined?

Comment: @callum how to make user interface for media player in python? Python VS C#(For user interface)? Which one is the best?